# Double assignment of same variable in one expression in Python - does it have any purpose?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment

I was going through the [delta lake documentation page](https://delta.io/learn/getting-started).

There is a line like this :

```
from delta import *

builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

In the last line, we see a double assignment to the same variable `spark`. Does this do something different compared to :

```
spark = spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()

(vs)

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

In general, in python, is there a meaning to doing double assignment on the same variable ?

Comment: No, this is completely pointless, and maybe the result of a copy-paste error.

Comment: It does take a little extra time and it *can* make a real difference if the assignment has a side effect, for example [printing](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzknsbhYwT0nPykxp1gjJTO5RNOKSwEIUlLTFOLji1NLMktSc@PjNYpTc9J0FLJTK3UUyhJzSlOhykCgoCgzr0QDSYqLK7UiNVlDvULBVgGETYzUdeB2aGr@/w8A) (in this case printing twice instead of once). But that's a very artificial example, and I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga here. You could tell them so they fix it.

Comment: @KellyBundy ok, yes, using a non-standard namespace where updating the namespace has a side-effect, then it could matter.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Also tried [timing](https://tio.run/##LYsxCgIxEEX7nOI3SxJZhDUWIngSsbBIcIpMhskUevoYVn/1/oMnH3s1ThfRMYq2CqOayUBVmho0S36ac6UpOohx92/ccD75FTv93wMHpKvDnE1TicMvDT3GXYsSW/DLcSvgDo8FwWa15RRX9DjGFw) it, takes a handful of extra nanoseconds, which surely matters there :-). Nah, "copy&paste error" is exactly what I thought as well, at least that's how I myself occasionally duplicate stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer: It's meaningless.** Aside from a few wasted cycles redoing the same operation, the end result is identical.

**Long answer:** There are scenarios where it *could* have an effect, but none of them apply to code being executed normally (not through `eval`/`exec`) that is assigning to bare names (as opposed to assigning to a dotted name, where the descriptor protocol and other forms of attribute access customization could do weird things, or assigning to the result of a subscript expression like indexing/key-lookup or slicing, where the override of `__setitem__` could invoke arbitrary code).

In this case, on the CPython reference interpreter, all it does is add a couple extra instructions, one to duplicate the value at the top of the stack (so it can assign it to two targets without recomputing it), and one to assign to `spark` a second time (which just causes the old value assigned to it to be discarded).

The net effect of those two instructions is a couple unnecessary reference count manipulations (an extra incref when it doubles the top of the stack, and extra decref when it throws away the reference bound to `spark` the first time in favor of the one bound the second time), and either one additional C array lookup (for `STORE_FAST`/`STORE_DEREF`, when executed in a function to a function local or closure variable respectively, with the latter adding a couple cheap pointer dereferences to find/update the location of the closure variable) or one additional `dict` lookup (for the `STORE_NAME`/`STORE_GLOBAL` cases used for all other bare name assignments). The cost is trivial (low two-digit nanoseconds at most), so it's pretty harmless, just unnecessary.